# Check if certain fee exists in woocommerce order items

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have added extra fees to orders, one of which being *optional* (customer may choose it on checkout page using an AJAX radio button).

My goal is to echo a custom message in the customer's account, inside the details of **only** those orders where the optional fee was added.

So, basically, let's say I have 3 fees for a placed order (which are all stored in `wp_woocommerce_order_items` table as `fee` in the `order_item_type` column).

One of these 3 fees is called `Optional Fee` (*the one needed for my goal*).

**How do I check if this `Optional Fee` exists in the order's items?**

I have started with the following code, but it only gets me the name of the fee that was last stored and thus will not match with `Optional Fee`.

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

foreach ( $order->get_items('fee') as $item_id => $item ) {

    $fee_name = $item->get_name(); // This only gets me the name of the last fee stored in order items table.

    if ( $fee_name == 'Optional Fee' ) {

            echo 'Custom message';

        }
}
```

I think I should somehow get the list of fees (is it an array?) and check if `Optional Fee` exists in that list, but I can't figure out how to do it and couldn't find a working solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of trial & error, I finally figured it out. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works.

Basically, what I needed to do was to return a true statement if the `Optional Fee` was found when looping through the order's fee items.

If anybody ever needs something similar, here's the code:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$optional_fee_exists = false;

   $fee_counter = 0;

   foreach ( $order->get_fees() as $item_fee ) {

       $fee_counter++;

       $fee_name = $item_fee->get_name();

       if ( $fee_name == 'Optional Fee' ) {

           $optional_fee_exists = true;

       }
   }


if ( $optional_fee_exists ) {

   //do stuff;

}
```